# Change ActiveWorkbook When Multiple Instances Open

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I am opening an Excel file, and if it does not meet certain conditions, I am then creating a new workbook.  Problem I am having is that when the new workbook is created it is not by default set to the `activeworkbook`so when I try to use `activeworkbook.saveas()`it saves the 1st workbook, with inaccurate data.

This is what I am using to create the new workbook:

```
Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = this.Application.Workbooks.Add();
```

Can someone show me how to change activeworkbook in Excel when multiple workbooks are opened?

BTW this is Excel 2007 I am working with.

Copy worksheet to new workbook

```
ws = wb.Sheets["Mitchell"];
((Excel.Worksheet)ws).Copy();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Configuration Details:**

- Code is written in vb.net using Visual Studio 2010 Professional
- All example code is placed in the `ThisAddIn_Startup` event handler of the
  Application-Level Add-In for Excel 2010
- In project references (right click project > properties >
  references) make sure there is a check beside  `Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel`

---

When multiple worksheets are open, I use `For Each` to loop through the collection and see the names...

```
    For Each wrkbk As Excel.Workbook In Me.Application.Workbooks

        MsgBox(wrkbk.Name)

    Next
```

Combine this with a `Select Case` and this allows you get at any workbook that is open.

```
    For Each wrkbk As Excel.Workbook In Me.Application.Workbooks

        Select Case wrkbk.Name

            Case "Book1"

                wrkbk.Activate()

            Case "Book2"


            Case Else


         End Select

     Next
```

Now, tying it all together, you can do this:

1. Create a new workbook named **CustomWorkbook.xlsx**
2. Activate **Book1**, copy *Sheet1*, and paste it into CustomWorkbook.xlsx (rename sheet to *CopiedWorksheet*)
3. Activate CustomWorkbook.xlxs

   ```
   //Hide alerts so no prompts display when using SaveAs to rename new workbook
   Me.Application.DisplayAlerts = False

   //Programatically create a new workbook
   Dim myWrkbk As Excel.Workbook
   myWrkbk = Me.Application.Workbooks.Add()

   //Name new workbook
   myWrkbk.SaveAs("CustomWorkbook")

   //Set Book1 as the active workbook (so can copy sheet)
   Application.Workbooks("Book1").Activate()

   //Create a new worksheet variable
   Dim sourceWrksht As Excel.Worksheet
   sourceWrksht = Application.Worksheets("Sheet1")
   sourceWrksht.Range("A1").Value = "Text in a Cell"

   //Select Sheet1 and copy into CustomWorkbook and paste as first sheet
   sourceWrksht.Select()
   sourceWrksht.Copy(Before:=Application.Workbooks("CustomWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets(1))

   //Rename copied worksheet
   Dim destinationWrksht As Excel.Worksheet
   destinationWrksht = Application.Workbooks("CustomWorkbook.xlsx").Sheets(1)

   destinationWrksht.Name = "CopiedWorksheet"

   //Loop through all open workbooks in Excel Application
   For Each wrkbk As Excel.Workbook In Me.Application.Workbooks


       Select Case wrkbk.Name

           Case "CustomWorkbook.xlsx"

               wrkbk.Activate()

           Case "Book1"


           Case Else

       End Select

   Next

   //Set Excel to show alerts again
   Me.Application.DisplayAlerts = True
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Simply call the `Activate()` method on the workbook you want to show.

When you create a new workbook you could use this:

```
Excel.Wokrbook oldWorkbook = this.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = this.Application.Workbooks.Add();

oldWorkbook.Activate();
```

And after a while:

```
newWorkbook.Activate();
```

See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bh14x010%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) at MSDN.

Except:

> The Activate method of the Workbooks collection activates a Microsoft Office Excel workbook and selects the first sheet in the workbook.

**EDIT:**

This works for me:

```
Excel.Workbook oldWorkbook = this.Application.ActiveWorkbook;

this.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets["name"].Copy();

Excel.Workbook newWorkbook = this.Application.ActiveWorkbook;
```

old = Book1

new = Book2

Comment: Sweet!  That solved problem one.  How would I set activeworkbook if I am using `((Excel.Worksheet)ws).Copy();`.

Comment: @user2954053: Glad it helped. Which do you want to select? You can use `ws.Parent` to get the parent of the sheet.

Comment: I want to select the 'new' workbook that is created from the Copy command.

Comment: when I use the statement above it copies the selected worksheet to a new workbook.  It does not copy the selected worksheet within the same workbook.  I'll post full code.

Comment: that value remains the same as my source workbook.  I.E. the workbook I copied From.

Comment: @user2954053: did you see my edit? Forgot to mention it to you.

Comment: I am not using an Add-In just using Interop.Excel

Comment: @user2954053: sorry, changed it to `this`.